# Can I configure the agent pool for a pipeline outside the YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am aware that I can configure the agent pool in my pipeline's YAML but when I was configuring a new pipeline, at some point a dialog popped up asking me which agent pool to use. I cannot remember where or how and I've spent 30 minutes clicking every option trying to find it!

Where can I link an agent pool to a pipeline in DevOps? I know it's there somewhere!

Comment: If you're using YAML, the correct place is in the YAML. You may be thinking of classic pipelines, which only had a GUI.

Comment: @DanielMann I wonder if I inadvertently viewed the classic GUI when starting out, then couldn't find it once I had created YAML. If YAML is the _only_ place I can configure a pool when using YAML, your comment could make a reasonable answer IMO. I wondered if I can manually force a build on a specific pool?